# Why am I getting the error "MobileMe does not sync with Microsoft Exchange Server"?

Tags: data-synchronization, mobileme, windows, exchange-activesync

I am getting this error message every time a meeting request comes through, but I am not syncing anything with outlook or exchange, so I don't know what to change to get rid of it.

[image]

These are my sync settings.

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Did you check your Outlook configuration? It seems like the problem it's in there

Comment: I'm not even asking it to sync calendars ... the outlook configuration should not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution: (Outlook 2007 with Exchange server 2003)

Remove MobileMe from the Outlook COM add-ins

Tools -> Trust Center -> Add-ins

then click on Go to Manage Add-ins

scroll down and disable then remove MobileMe from the list.

Comment: For me, the solution to remove the add-in in Outlook does not work.

Comment: You need to run Outlook as an admin. This worked for me, but then the next day it does not work anymore, and now it doesnt work at all (the error comes up as frequently as it ever did).

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook configuration is *precisely* what matters here. As per the error you got: **MobileMe does not sync calendars with Microsoft Outlook when Outlook is configured to use Microsoft Exchange Server.**

Calendar syncing takes place via calDAV. The account settings are specifically IMAP.

Unless there are custom profiles or the Outlook PST file is damaged, I'd suggest simply removing the account from Outlook, and signing out on the MobileMe Control Panel, then setting it up fresh.

Comment: David, your answer doesn't make any sense -- how does Outlook affect the syncing of Safari bookmarks?

Comment: How does bookmark syncing have anything to do with this problem?